# Isekai manga where the main character wanted to learn magic but had to leave his home town because he didn't want to marry his sister

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

The main character wanted to learn magic ever since he was a little boy before he died and isekai to the world. He was reincarnated into a baby with red eyes and white hair, just like everyone in his village. But as he was beginning to master his mage craft he had to leave as soon as he realized that he had to marry his sister. So he left and became an adventurer.

Answer (score 9):

This is [Saikyou Juzoku Tensei: Majutsu Otaku no Utopia](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/saikyou-juzoku-tensei-majutsu-otaku-no-utopia).

> I, who should have died after being hit by a car, was born again in
>   another world.
>
> However, I was born in a shady minor family that used magic and
>   controlled wooden puppets called the Marren Clan.
>
> Possessing a strong interest in magic since my previous life, I spend
>   my time zealously studying magic to the point where even the people in
>   the vicinity draw back.
>
> One day, I heard I was to be married to my little sister when I turned
>   16 in accordance with the traditions of the Marren Clan and decided to
>   flee to the city.
>
> For now, since I have the strongest magic, I guess I should idle
>   around making only enough money so that I don’t have to work for my
>   whole life.

[image]